# How to display/put a button inside an ObjectListView column?

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I learn to use [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) in C# to show my MySQL data and I try to draw/put a delete button inside column so that when I click it, it will delete the row.

I know how to draw an image or a progress bar inside a column, but the problem is I don't know how to put a button inside. When I search Google, I found that someone said have to use custom renderer to draw a button, but I don't know how.

How to put button inside the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13191759/1790864) explains how to use the CellEditStarting event to delete a row when a specific column of that row is clicked.

<strike>You only have to add a custom renderer to that solution if you want to display some kind of delete symbol</strike>.

You don't have to implement a custom renderer to display some kind of button-image for that row. You can use the ImageGetter. I improved [the answer i already referenced to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13191759/1790864). It contains an example now.

Extract:

```
// assign an ImageList containing at least one image to SmallImageList
objectListView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;

// always display image from index 0 as default image for deleteColumn
deleteColumn.ImageGetter = delegate {
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: thanks for your help.. now I just need to know how to make a custom renderer to draw button inside column.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but there should be no need to "insert" a button in a control sense. It should be enough to draw an image inside that column that represent a button.

Comment: @eric_dofen: I improved this answer and added a complete example on how to use an image in the delete column [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13191759/1790864).