# ObjectListView show icons

Tags: c#, icons, objectlistview

Trying to put icons in ObjectListview, here's my piece of code where icon should have been put:

```
objectListView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;

        deleteColumn.IsEditable = true;
        deleteColumn.ImageGetter = delegate
        {
            return 0;
        };
        deleteColumn.AspectGetter = delegate
        {
            return "Delete";
        };
```

imageList1 already have an image, this code should have put an icon next to "Delete", but it did not appear at all, looked through cookbooks and Google and I still have no idea. Can anyone help me?

this is the full form code in case needed:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        objectListView1.AllowDrop = true;
        objectListView1.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(objectListView1_DragEnter);
        objectListView1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(objectListView1_DragDrop);
        objectListView1.CellEditActivation = BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.CellEditActivateMode.SingleClick;
        objectListView1.CellEditStarting += deleteItems;
        objectListView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;

        deleteColumn.IsEditable = true;
        deleteColumn.ImageGetter = delegate
        {
            return 0;
        };
        deleteColumn.AspectGetter = delegate
        {
            return "Delete";
        };
    }

    private void objectListView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void objectListView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, true))
        {
            string[] droppedFiles = (string[]) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            foreach (string path in droppedFiles)
            {
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    FileObject fo = new FileObject(path, "added later"); 
                    objectListView1.AddObject(fo);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void deleteItems(object sender, BrightIdeasSoftware.CellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Column == deleteColumn)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            objectListView1.RemoveObject(e.RowObject);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on MSDN? They usually provide sufficient examples. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.smallimagelist.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.aspx).

Comment: ObjectListView is not actually a Microsoft product, and the problem seems to be with it rather than with the ImageList.

Comment: thanks guys, problem is solved, my `ShowImageOnSubItems` is set to false, thank you very much form the answer below

Answer (score 7):

In order for images to appear next to the text in a column, you must:

1. Connect the `ObjectListView` to an `ImageList` (using the `SmallImageList` property);
2. Install an `ImageGetter` delegate for the column that must show the images;
3. Make sure that there are actually images in the `ImageList`.

With this done, images will appear (I just tested this).

There is one catch, though. From your question, I suspect that the "Delete" column may not be the first column in the `ObjectListView`. The above steps only allow you to show an image in the very first column. For subsequent columns, you will have to set the `ShowImagesOnSubItems` property to True. Could that be it?

Comment: no, delete column is on the third column (requirement by the client, can't change it)

Comment: hey thanks, i missed the `ShowImagesOnSubItems`, really a problem because there's no tutorial (or maybe I haven't looked hard enough) about it. Thanks a lot :)