# C# ObjectListView Button with icon?

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I am using ObjectListView! It's wonderful! I've a problem OLV use details, item column is Button! How to set Button icon? I'm sorry for writing wrong :)

Comment: Yes set button's icon Example delete icon or edit iicon

Answer (score 1):

Suppose! You have a column named as `olvButton` in you `ObjectListView`. You just need to create a `ImageGetter` delegate while initializing you `ObjectListView` and return Image.

```
private void InitializeObjectListView()
{
    //Other settings for ObjectListView
    this.ObjectLV.RowHeight = 40;
    this.ObjectLV.EmptyListMsg = "No item found";

    //Set Image index for Button Column
    this.olvButton.ImageGetter = delegate(object x)
    {
        //ImageList is a control in which I have added one Image.
        return imagesList.Images[0];
    };
}
```

For more information [Have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15566199/3814721)