# ObjectListView with picture buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I want to create a listView with remove buttons like this in WinForms:

[image]

After some searching, it seems like ObjectListView is the way to go. After much struggling, I've got text to show up for my items, but I can't get the icons to show up. I've tried going the `ImageAspectName` route and the `ImageGetter` route - no success. Here's what I've got for some sample code:

My class:

```
public class item
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Image RemoveButton { get; set; }
}
```

And the code for putting the items in the ObjectListView:

```
item listItem1 = new item();
listItem1.Title = "this is a test title";
listItem1.RemoveButton = Properties.Resources.Remove;
List<item> listItems = new List<item>() { listItem1 };
objectListView1.SetObjects(listItems);
olvColumn2.ImageGetter += delegate (object rowObject) { return ((item)rowObject).RemoveButton; };
```

My first question is: can I just use the `Properties.Resources.Remove` like I've got above? What should the Build Action be for it? Just "Resource"?

EDIT:

If I try to use `objectListView1.SmallImageList` then it throws an exception (IndexOutOfRangeException):

```
ImageList imageList = new ImageList();
imageList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.Remove);
objectListView1.SmallImageList = imageList;
```

I have also tried using a different size of the same image (16x16 instead of 256x256) but to no avail.

Here is my simple test project in case anyone wants to tell me what I'm doing wrong: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_-6KdFaC6WiMmMxU0JaUktUeWs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ObjectListView - Delete a row by clicking on a designated column with fixed content/text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629417/objectlistview-delete-a-row-by-clicking-on-a-designated-column-with-fixed-cont)

Comment: @Rev1.0 I see how that looks like a duplicate (my question and that question both want the same end goal), but their question is just a general "how do I do this" whereas I'm struggling with getting images to show up (Please reread the questions at the end of my post)

Comment: Assigning the image from the Resources should work that way. Did you set the "OwnerDraw" property on the OLV? IIRC its required to display images.

Comment: Are you sure you want the remove button be part of you data object? Why? Isn't it the same for all rows? Its seems odd.

Comment: Yes, I have set the OwnerDraw property to true. The button will be the same for all rows - is there a better way to set it, then?

Comment: Then you should probably do it the way its suggested in the linked answer. Add an SmallImageList with the Image and assign it to the OLV. Then return the Image by returning the image index.

Comment: Did you set ShowImagesOnSubItems to true?

Comment: Yes, I had set that to true. Also, see my updated question in regards to SmallImageList

Comment: Did you return index 0 from the ImageGetter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147943/discussion-between-derekantrican-and-rev1-0).

Comment: Did you solve it by changing the image size?

Comment: @Rev1.0 Unfortunately, no